# how to get index of array where value was found

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble getting the index of a value where a specific value was found. The problem is, names array could have 2 indexes. How can I find the array of the index where the value was found?

Edit: Updated array

```
    namesArray: [
      {
        "fillNum": 1,
        "personalInfo": {
          "polyType": 2,
          "moreInfo": {},
          "nameInfo": {
            "lastName": "smith",
          },
        }
      }
    ], 

let hasLastName = names.some(e => e === nameInfo);
        if (hasLastName) {
          lastName = names[0].nameInfo.lastName;
        }
```

Old -

```
let hasLastName = names.some(lastName => lastName);
    if (hasLastName) {
      lastName = names[0].nameInfo.lastName;
    }
```

Comment: can you please provide an array example and your expected output?

Comment: Sorry - should have added that. Updated in the original question.

        namesArray: [
          {
            "fillNum": 1,
            "personalInfo": {
              "polyType": 2,
              "moreInfo": {},
              "nameInfo": {
                "lastName": "smith",
              },
            }
          }
        ],

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an array method for that:

```
const indexOfName = names.findIndex(element => element === lastName)
```

EDIT:

```
const indexOfName = namesArray.findIndex(element => element.personalInfo.nameInfo.lastName === lastName)
```

This will work for the structure in your updated question.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But can you check my edit - what about with more nested objects?

Comment: The same idea applies, you just have to go looking for it a bit more, see my updated answer

Comment: Sorry - one more question. What if that obj doesn't exist? Or if the the whole array doesn't exist?

Comment: Then you'll need to add some checks for safety, for example: `const indexOfName = (namesArray || []).findIndex((el) => el && el.personalInfo && el.personalInfo.nameInfo && el.personalInfo.nameInfo.lastName == lastName)`, or using Lodash (similar functions exist in Ramda and Underscore): `const indexOfName = (namesArray || []).findIndex((el) => _.get('personalInfo.nameInfo.lastName', el) === lastName)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) function, e.g.

```js
const names = ['Brown', 'Johnson', 'Smith'];
const lastName = 'Johnson'

const index = names.findIndex(element => element === lastName)

alert("index: " + index); 
// prints "index: 1"
```